# What is the reason behind having function serializable in Spark.?

Tags: apache-spark

I want to get exact reason behind having functions serializable in Spark and want to know the if possible want to know the scenarios, where can be issues because of Serialization,

As far as my understanding goes, to ensure seam less no side-effect parallel processing, instead of sending the data liike imperative paradigm,
function will be sent to the node and data gets processed parallely.

Is my above thought Correct.??? As far as my study, Functional programming is a very good way forward for parallel processing/concurrent programming, so i thought this is the reason.

As we are passing function, is it the security reason behind having functions serializable.?

Thanks In advance.

Comment: The functions are being transformed into data, and that data is being passed from the Spark Driver to the Spark Workers. This is how the Spark Workers get the instructions of which work to perform. A Function in Spark is a type of object, and an object needs to be Serializable in order that it can be marshalled to data, passed across the network, and unmarshalled back to a function at the other end. The reason is therfore to do with Spark being a distributed system.

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind needing serializable closures as function arguments in calls to the `RDD` API in Spark is that you write and define those functions on your driver machine (very often your laptop), and you need to ship those functions to your executors (very often, not your laptop, but other machines in your network).

Therefore, irrespective of the benefits of statelessness in functional programming, the serializability is effectively used to ship code to different machines across a network. Here are [tips](http://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/troubleshooting/javaionotserializableexception.html) for handling serializability issues if you need them.